# The index is listing everything, cancancan is not filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

I have this view that lists all pops, only it depends on the user, it should not appear everything, so I was using the cancancan to filter, but it is not working anymore.

my view(pops/index.html.erb):

```
<% if @pops.present? %>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Titulo</th>
            <th colspan="4"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <% @pops.each do |pop| %>
      <tbody>
        <tr>                      
          <% if can? :index, Pop %> 
              <td scope="row"><%= pop.title  %></td>   
          <% end %>    
          <% if can? :show, Pop %>        
            <td><%= link_to 'Mostrar', pop %></td> 
          <% end %> 
          <% if can? :edit, Pop %>    
            <td><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_pop_path(pop) %></td> 
          <% end %> 
          <% if can? :delete, Pop %>    
            <td><%= link_to 'Excluir', pop, method: :delete %></td>     
          <% end %> 
          <% if can? :index_pdf, Pop %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Exportar', index_pdf_path(pop) %></td>
          <% end %>         
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <% end %>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

my model

```
class Pop < ApplicationRecord
  enum charge: {
            Auxiliar: 1,
            Analista: 2,
            Coordenador: 3,
            Supervisor: 4,
            Gerente: 5,
            Diretor: 6
        }
    enum status: {
        active: 0,
        inactive: 1
    }
    has_many :pop_groups
    has_many :groups, :through => :pop_groups, :dependent => :destroy        
end
```

my ability

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
        if user
            if user.kind == 'user'
                if user.charge == 'Auxiliar'               
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Auxiliar', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq                           
                end 
                if user.charge == 'Analista'
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Auxiliar', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Analista', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq
                 end
                if user.charge == 'Coordenador'
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Auxiliar', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Analista', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Coordenador'                     
                 end
                if user.charge == 'Supervisor'
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Auxiliar', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Analista', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Coordenador', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq 
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Supervisor', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq                    
                end 
                if user.charge == 'Gerente'
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Auxiliar', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Analista', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Coordenador', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq 
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Supervisor', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq
                    can [:index_pdf, :show, :read, :view, :index], Pop, status: 'active', charge: 'Gerente', id: PopGroup.where(group_id: user.group_ids).pluck(:pop_id).uniq                   
               end 
                if user.charge == 'Diretor'
                    can :index_pdf, Pop, status: 'active'
                    can :read, Pop, status: 'active'
                end            
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I tried in many ways but I could not get him to take what the user could not see. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to make it work. Here is the code.

```
<% @pops.each do |pop| %>
          <tbody>
            <% if can? :show, pop %>
                <tr>                      
                  <td><%= pop.title if can? :show, pop %></td>                
                    <td><%= link_to 'Visualizar', pop if can? :show, pop %></td>                  
                    <td><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_pop_path(pop) if can? :edit, pop %></td> 
                    <td><%= link_to 'Excluir', pop, method: :delete if can? :delete, pop %></td> 
                    <td><%= link_to 'Exportar', index_pdf_path(pop) if can? :index_pdf, pop %></td>     
                </tr>
            <% end %>
<%end%>
```

The first 'if' is that the 'each' does not create blank lines. The others are the tests to see if the user has permission.